# Loading large data from Firebase into UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a comparatively large dataset (about 1,000 rows) that need to be filled into the UITableView from Firebase. I am also using sections and search functionality in the UITableView.

This is how it looks at the moment with the required functionality:

[image: Screengrab]

As you can see, section functionality has been used in UITableView. But `the issue` that I face currently is `extremely slow loading` of data. I have `localPersistenceEnabled` but it still takes about 3-4 seconds to populate all data and the experience is less than pleasant.

How do I fix this? I read about Pagination but I also want to preserve the functionality of sections. For sections, this is the code I'm using:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    self.racks.removeAll()
    self.sectionals.removeAll()
    self.tableView.reloadData()

    ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "chamber").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in

        // Manage TableView Sections & Rows for Rack Additions

        var doesSectionExist = false
        let segment = (snapshot.value as! [String : AnyObject])["segment"] as! String

        if self.sectionals.contains(segment){
            // There's already an index present for this letter.
            doesSectionExist = true
            var snapshotData = self.racks[segment]
            snapshotData?.append(snapshot)
            self.racks[segment] = snapshotData
        }
        else{
            self.racks[segment] = [snapshot]
            self.sectionals.append(segment)
        }

        self.allRacks.append(snapshot)

        self.sectionals = self.sectionals.sorted()

        if !doesSectionExist{
            self.tableView.insertSections(IndexSet(integer: self.sectionals.index(of: segment)!), with: .fade)
        }
        else{
            //let rowCount = self.customers[firstChar]?.count
            self.tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: self.sectionals.index(of: segment)!), with: .fade)
            //self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: rowCount!-1, inSection: self.sectionals.indexOf(firstChar)!)], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }

    })

}


override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
        return 1
    }
    else{
        return sectionals.count
    }
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
        return "Top Matches"
    }
    else{
        return sectionals[section]
    }
}

override func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
    if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
        return nil
    }
    else{
        return sectionals
    }
}
```

So the idea is to provide section index titles for quick access and improve loading time to load such a large dataset.

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38274568/swift-firebase-search-in-database

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39320213/filtered-searches-with-firebase

Comment: Hi @srinivasn : More than the search functionality, I need sections to be enabled. With pagination (for example), I load the first 30 elements that can go on screen but how do I determine all section options?

Comment: Whatever depending on search you need to get the data from fire base assign section table

Comment: Search is secondary. I want to the tableview to load quicker when the user opens that screen/view. So I cannot just use `queryStartingAt` on load.. Or maybe I did not follow your point, could you please elaborate?